# office 365 Admin: Delegate a mailbox account (Full access) to all other mailboxes by default

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Hi In office 365 Admin (Exchange) Is there a way to delegate one mailbox account which will automatically becomes as a delegate to all other accounts, even up on adding a new user in the future?

Example want a mailbox called AdminMailbox to be Delegate to all other mailboxes, even once I add a new user in the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to schedule a PowerShell script weekly where you query all the mailboxes and add the permission. Or if you also Azure you might be able to schedule it in Azure Automation as a runbook.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion above, there is no original method to meet this need, you will need to write a script and let it run automatically on a regular basis.

And the command you will need for [granting full access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-permissions-for-recipients#use-exchange-online-powershell-to-assign-the-full-access-permission-to-mailboxes):

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <MailboxIdentity> -User <DelegateIdentity> -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All [-AutoMapping $false]
```

Comment: Thank you both, yes i can run a command to grant full access to all mailbox using this, but I have to repeat with new users  

Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox,SharedMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Add-MailboxPermission -User AdminMailbox -AccessRights FullAccess -Confirm:$false

Comment: Hi, yes, that's the easiest way to meet this requirement. Like this similar question discussed here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2149048-automatically-add-send-as-permission-to-new-mailboxes